# Getting Segmentation Fault when trying to assign value in Binary Tree

Tags: c++

I'm doing a BinaryTree project for my C++ class, and I keep getting a segmentation fault. It keeps breaking where I'm trying to assign x to value in my setValue() function in my TreeNode class. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Here is my TreeNode class:

```
#ifndef TREENODE_H
#define TREENODE_H
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class TreeNode{
private:
    T value;
    TreeNode* left;
    TreeNode* right;
public:
    TreeNode();
    TreeNode(const T&);
    ~TreeNode();
    T& getValue();
    TreeNode* getLeft() const;
    TreeNode* getRight() const;
    void setValue(const T&);
    void setLeft(TreeNode*);
    void setRight(TreeNode*);
};
template<typename T>
TreeNode<T>::TreeNode()
{
    value = 0;
    left = NULL;
    right = NULL;
}
template<typename T>
TreeNode<T>::TreeNode(const T& x)
{
    value = x;
    left = NULL;
    right = NULL;
}
template<typename T>
TreeNode<T>::~TreeNode()
{
    if(left!=NULL)
        delete left;
    if(right!=NULL)
        delete right;
}
template<typename T>
void TreeNode<T>::setValue(const T& x)
{
    value=x;
}
template<typename T>
T& TreeNode<T>::getValue()
{
    return value;
}
template<typename T>
TreeNode<T>* TreeNode<T>::getLeft() const
{
    return left;
}
template<typename T>
TreeNode<T>* TreeNode<T>::getRight() const
{
    return right;
}
template<typename T>
void TreeNode<T>::setLeft(TreeNode* x)
{
    if(left!=NULL)
        delete left;
    left=new TreeNode;
    left=x;
}
template<typename T>
void TreeNode<T>::setRight(TreeNode* x)
{
    if(right!=NULL)
        delete right;
    right=new TreeNode;
    right=x;
}

#endif
```

Here is my BinaryTree class:

```
#ifndef BINARYTREE_H
#define BINARYTREE_H
#include "TreeNode.h"
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class BinaryTree:public TreeNode<T>{
public:
    BinaryTree();
    BinaryTree(const T&);
    ~BinaryTree();
    BinaryTree(const BinaryTree&);
    void insert(const T&);
    void inorder_traversal();
private:
    TreeNode<T>* root;
    TreeNode<T>* getRoot();
    void setRoot(const T&);
    void destroyTree(TreeNode<T>*);
};
template<typename T>
BinaryTree<T>::BinaryTree()
{
    root = new TreeNode <T>;
    root = NULL;
}
template<typename T>
BinaryTree<T>::BinaryTree(const T& x)
{
    root = new TreeNode <T>(x);
}
template<typename T>
BinaryTree<T>::BinaryTree(const BinaryTree<T>& A)
{
    root=A.getRoot();
}
template<typename T>
void BinaryTree<T>::destroyTree(TreeNode<T>* leaf)
{
    if(leaf!=NULL)
    {
        destroyTree(leaf->getLeft());
        destroyTree(leaf->getRight());
        delete leaf;
    }
}
template<typename T>
BinaryTree<T>::~BinaryTree()
{
    if(root!=NULL)
        destroyTree(root);
}
template<typename T>
TreeNode<T>* BinaryTree<T>::getRoot()
{
    return root;
}
template<typename T>
void BinaryTree<T>::setRoot(const T& x)
{
    if(root!=NULL)
    {
        delete root;
        root=new TreeNode<T>;
    }
    root->setValue(x);
}
template<typename T>
void BinaryTree<T>::insert(const T& x)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        setRoot(x);
    else
    {
        TreeNode<T>* rootTemp = new TreeNode < T > ;
        rootTemp = root;
        bool insertionComplete = false;
        while (!insertionComplete)
        {
            if (x < rootTemp->getValue())
            {
                if ((rootTemp->getLeft()) == NULL)
                {
                    (rootTemp->getLeft())->setValue(x);
                    insertionComplete = true;
                }
                else
                    rootTemp = rootTemp->getLeft();
            }
            else
            {
                if ((rootTemp->getRight()) == NULL)
                {
                    (rootTemp->getRight())->setValue(x);
                    insertionComplete = true;
                }
                else
                    rootTemp = rootTemp->getRight();
            }
        }
        root = rootTemp;
        delete rootTemp;
    }
}

#endif
```

and here is my simple main.cpp that I'm trying to run:

```
#include "TreeNode.h"
#include "BinaryTree.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    BinaryTree<int> x(2);
    std::cout << "first\n";
    x.insert(1);
    std::cout<<"END\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: left=new TreeNode; left=x; and such are all memory leaks

Comment: I suggest you use the debugger.  It is an essential tool to learn and use.  You can't write code like this and expect it to work the first time.

Answer (score 2):

In your class, you have this piece of code

```
if (x < rootTemp->getValue())
            {
                if ((rootTemp->getLeft()) == NULL)
                {
                    (rootTemp->getLeft())->setValue(x);
                    insertionComplete = true;
                }
                else
                    rootTemp = rootTemp->getLeft();
            }
            else
            {
                if ((rootTemp->getRight()) == NULL)
                {
                    (rootTemp->getRight())->setValue(x);
                    insertionComplete = true;
                }
                else
                    rootTemp = rootTemp->getRight();
            }
```

Where you are basically calling `setValue()` when the object is `NULL`. You have to initialize `left` and/or `right` from the `TreeNode` object before use them

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly to go about initializing left and/or right :( I thought they are already initialized when I created rootTemp?

Comment: @mrdanley In the `TreeNode` constructors, you only do `left = NULL; right = NULL;`. So, just call the constructor on them: `left = new TreeNode<T>(); right = new TreeNode<T>();`

Comment: thanks, I tried fixing the constructor to:
value = 0;
 left = new TreeNode<T>;
 left = NULL;
 right = new TreeNode<T>;
 right = NULL;

but now im getting a stack overflow error

Comment: @mrdanley but with that fix code all you are provoking is a memory leak. Why do you set them to `NULL` after you initialized them?

Comment: oh I see what you mean, I think I need to do some more readup on memory allocation.
even if I remove the left=NULL and right=NULL, I'm still getting a stack overflow error and its driving me crazy :(

Comment: ok I got the problem fixed, I just needed to make it left=new TreeNode[] with the brackets :) thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Without too much debugging (which I leave to you as homework), this piece of code:

```
    TreeNode<T>* rootTemp = new TreeNode < T > ;
    rootTemp = root;
```

looks like you create an object (`rootTemp`) and then you immediately throw it away by reassigning it to your `root` object. Investigate further the logic implemented here.

Answer (score 0):

```
                if ((rootTemp->getLeft()) == NULL)
                {
                    (rootTemp->getLeft())->setValue(x);
```

You are checking if getLeft is NULL and then you are dereferencing it.

Comment: how would I go about assigning x to the value of rootTemp without dereferencing it?

Comment: Create a temporary note and call setLeft() on the rootTemp

Answer (score 0):

your void BinaryTree::insert(const T& x) has some flaws:

You create a new TreeNode object and immediatly overwrite the pointer to it. That new object is now lost. into space. Just drop the first line

```
TreeNode<T>* rootTemp = new TreeNode < T >;
rootTemp = root;
```

In the end you overwrite your root node, the old root node would be lost now. into space.
Then you delete your new root node (rootTemp). any next access to your root node will now crash. Just drop both lines.

```
root = rootTemp;
delete rootTemp;
```

When you found an empty pointer to a node (the pointer is NULL), you call setValue on that. NULL means there is no object behind that which could execute your action => segmentation fault (simply said you access a non-existing object)

```
 (rootTemp->getLeft())->setValue(x);
```

Your TreeNode though offers the function setLeft() which would be appropriate. Here would also be the ideal place to create your new TreeNode:

```
rootTemp->setLeft(new TreeNode<T>(x));
```

You don't even need to call set value due too your constructor overloading.

As pointed out by others you haven't fully understood how pointers work and what new and delete do with them.

- new => create in memory and call constructor member function, return address of memory
- delete => call destructor member function and delete memory (tells memory mangement that memory can now be used by others)
- pointer => just an address to tell your CPU where to look for the object in it's memory

This will get you to END. but your program crashes due to a double delete on the same memory after that. If you are running linux you can use gdb to debug your program. Just call gdb ./your-program in a terminal from the right directory. "start" will start the program, "continue" will tell the program to continue runnung after a halt (called breakpoint) and "backtrace" is helpfull to show you which function was where called when your program is stopped. Most IDEs have an interface to gdb or include their own debugger.

Going further you also have some extra memory leaks (you create objects which are then lost and never deleted). You could search for them with valgrind --leak-check=full ./your-program